# Incorrect bullet in the AFP file created using Apache FOP

Tags: java, apache-fop

We are trying to create an AFP file using Apache FOP. the AFP file is getting generated but the bullets which gets renedered in the file are not correct. We want a round bullet but instead we are getting a square bullet.

In the FO file if the encoding is set to "ISO-8859-1" and run the FOP utils locally to generate the AFP we are able to see the round bullet.

If in the FO file we have the encoding as "UTF-8" then we see the Square bullet in the generated AFP. This created of AFP is happening through a java program. The java program will read all the fonts, create the FO file and then generate the AFP file.

What can be the issue?

We have done the following:

In the XSL file we have the output encoding as: encoding="ISO-8859-1" and the circular bullet value as `&#x2022;`

When the java code creates the FO file, we see the circular bullet but when the AFP gets created it will be square bullet.

We tried with encoding as "UTF-8" also but same result. So what else are we missing here?

Comment: If you get the correct result calling FOP from a command prompt and the wrong result when calling FOP from java code, could it be that the code is not using the configuration file?

Comment: When the java code is creating the FO we see circular bullet but the generated AFP has the square bullet. So what configuration can we check?

Comment: It is likely the font being used